# Remote output from Get-SmbAccess

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have this code bit, I am trying to get to work in a script:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess}
```

I would like it to return the AccessRights as if was run locally - but this return numbers instead of text. Like AccessRight '0', '2' etc.

```
Name     AccountName                      AccessRight
----     -----------                      -----------
IPC$     BUILTIN\Administrators                     0
IPC$     BUILTIN\Backup Operators                   0
IPC$     NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                   0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: the SMB cmdlets are not available with ps5.1 on win7, so this is a guess ... that looks like an _enum_. if so, you will likely need to derive the text value for that at the source - perhaps with `.ToString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 'AccessRight' is defined as a 'ScriptProperty', the friendly name is being calculate at access time. That is, PowerShell only looks it up when you access the property (e.g. when building the table output).  Use `Get-Member` to see the definition:

```
Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess | Get-Member | Format-List *

TypeName   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Smb/MSFT_SmbShareAccessControlEntry
Name       : AccessRight
MemberType : ScriptProperty
Definition : System.Object AccessRight {get=[Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.SmbShare.ShareAccessRight] 
             ($this.PSBase.CimInstanceProperties['AccessRight'].Value);}
```

As the information needed to convert it is not loaded locally by default when making remote calls, PowerShell can only show you the raw integer value:

```
TypeName   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SmbShareAccessControlEntry
Name       : AccessRight
MemberType : Property
Definition : uint32 AccessRight {get;}
```

You could write some code to convert it yourself (say as another calculated property), or a quick hack would be to run the SMB cmdlets locally before running them remotely to force the necessary definitions to be loaded:

```
Get-SmbShare | Out-Null

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'RemoteServer' -ScriptBlock {
    Get-SmbShare | Get-SmbShareAccess
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
$result = Get-SmbShare -CimSession $computers | Get-SmbShareAccess | Select-Object -Property Name, AccountName, AccessControlType, AccessRight, PSComputerName
```

Note: Select-Object is optional. I have used it to show PSComputerName Property, so to identify, which computer provides the output

[image]

Hope it helps!